# TimerTask alternative

Tags: java, oop

Basically I have 2 classes: **Main** and **Population**. What I'm trying to do is to increase `Population.total` by 100 using `Population.grow()` every second. `Population` already extends another class so I can't have it extend `TimerTask`.

This is the code for **`Population`**:

```
public class Population extends AnotherClass{
private int total = 0;
 void grow(){
 this.population = this.population + 100;
 }
}
```

And the **`Main`** class:

```
public class Main{
 public static void main(String [] args){
 Population population = new Population();
 }
}
```

Normally what I'd do is just make `Population` extend [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to perform updates like this:

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(grow(), 1000);
```

The problem is neither `Main` nor `Population` can extend `Timer` or any other class as I need `population` to be declared inside the `Main` class. So how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Create an InnerClass that extends Timer. When it fires you can call to the OuterClass. You might also look into the Observer design pattern.

Comment: @Spidy why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: Didn't have time for a high quality response. Evgeniy's answer is what I'm talking about (except if grow is private, you'd need that timer code inside the class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could make it implement `Runnable` and use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 4):

try like this

```
    final Population population = new Population();
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            population.grow();
        }
    }, 1000);
```